# How to get content tag in this span?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<span itemprop="price" content="34.99" class="">
            <span class="current_price">
                  $ 34.99 
            </span>
          </span>
```

I get the itemprop span like so:

```
var itemProp = $('[itemprop="price"]');
```

After this I'm stuck on how to get the content..  I need the value of content in this case 34.99.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```js
var itemProp = $('[itemprop="price"]');
let content = itemProp.attr("content");
console.log(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span itemprop="price" content="34.99" class="">
  <span class="current_price">
    $ 34.99
  </span>
</span>
```